# How to find what sql process caused a delete in SQL 2000?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've seen queries for 2005/2008 to find what process caused a delete but have not seen anything for 2000. Is there anything?

Comment: A delete that already occured, or are you setting up a monitoring mechanism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For deletes, you can set up a DML trigger (see [CREATE TRIGGER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254(SQL.80).aspx)) in BOL for details.  Likely the most relevant information that you can obtain will come from [sysprocesses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260456(SQL.80).aspx), and you can query it using your spid (@@SPID).

Capture the info you're looking for, and log it out to a table you create for logging (along with the key values required to know which record(s) were deleted).

Comment: Can I get the spid of the process that deleted the record or will @@SPID give me a different spid?

Comment: @@SPID will return the spid of the session that deleted the row (which is what you're looking for).  Here's an example:

CREATE TABLE TestSpid (Col1 int)
GO
CREATE TRIGGER TestTrig ON TestSpid FOR DELETE
AS
BEGIN
 SELECT @@SPID
END
GO
INSERT TestSpid(Col1)
SELECT 1
GO
SELECT @@SPID
DELETE TestSpid

Comment: Damn...no line breaks in comments.  It works anyway, but it's ugly!

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about a current statement or process....
execute:

```
sp_who2
```

Answer (score 0):

Dropped a table, view etc. or deleted a row from a table?

Are you looking for an ongoing solution or to do a post-mortem?

Comment: ongoing solution. We aren't using transactions so I don't know that we could do post-mortem.

Comment: it would be on deleting a row.